# Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `403 Forbidden` response:

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

Why am I getting this error? I am using firebase php^5.14.1.

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: (truncated...) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(224): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(269): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(226): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait() #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Http\WrappedGuzzleClient.php(50): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('POST', 'signupNewUser', Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(219): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->request('POST', 'signupNewUser', Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(51): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->requestApi('signupNewUser', Array) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth.php(183): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->createUser(Object(Kreait\Firebase\Request\CreateUser)) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\accountmukera.php(40): Kreait\Firebase\Auth->createUser(Array) #15 {main} Next Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\AuthError: The request is missing a valid API key. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter.php:134 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter.php(50): Kreait\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter->convertGuzzleRequestException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(221): Kreait\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter->convertException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(51): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->requestApi('signupNewUser', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth.php(183): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->createUser(Object(Kreait\Firebase\Request\CreateUser)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\accountmukera.php(40): Kreait\Firebase\Auth->createUser(Array) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcns\admin\includes\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter.php on line 134

The code is

```
<?php 
session_start();
//error_reporting(0);


require_once'./includes/vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
//use Kreait\Firebase\Auth;


 $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/includes/secret/mcnsweb-ea923-firebase-adminsdk-40vau-468af8bd71.json');

 $factory = (new Factory())
 ->withDatabaseUri('https://mcnsweb-ea923-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');
 $database = $factory->createDatabase();
 
//include('includes/topheader.php');
//include('includes/leftsidebar.php');
//$reference = $database->getReference('users');
//$value = $reference->getValue();

//if($value>0){ 
    $auth = $factory->createAuth();

$userProperties = [
    'email' => 'sosi@gmail.com',
    'emailVerified' => false,
    'phoneNumber' => '+15555550100',
    'password' =>  "123456",
    'firstname' => "meron",
    'lastname' => "tesfaye",
  // 'displayName' => 'John Doe',
   // 'usertype'=> "department head",
   // 'imageUrl'=> upload(),
    'photoUrl' => 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    'disabled' => false,
];
$createdUser = $auth->createUser($userProperties);
// $database->getReference('users')->set('useraccount');
// $pushdata= $database->getReference('useraccount')->push($userProperties);
if($createdUser){
    echo "seccessful";
}


    ?>
```

Comment: Format your error. To put error, use three backticks (`) chararacters before code and after.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you are trying to access the database/create users without being logged in beforehand.

This line is creating a factory that uses the given service account and saves it as `$factory`.

```
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/includes/secret/mcnsweb-ea923-firebase-adminsdk-40vau-468af8bd71.json');
```

This line is **creating a different** factory and saving it as `$factory`.

```
$factory = (new Factory())
 ->withDatabaseUri('https://mcnsweb-ea923-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');
```

You need to combine these two statements, into:

```
$factory = (new Factory())
  ->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/includes/secret/mcnsweb-ea923-firebase-adminsdk-40vau-468af8bd71.json');
  ->withDatabaseUri('https://mcnsweb-ea923-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');
```